# rdd to df conversion using toDF() is giving error

Tags: pyspark, rdd

````
My code is:
```
sample1 = df_pat_jour_status_other_occurances.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.lh_pat_id, x.src_key, x.Journey_Status)).toDF()
type(sample1)
```
```
````

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1010.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1010.0 (TID 32154, LTIN214271.cts.com, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
```

Comment: As the error says "Python in worker has different version 3.7 than that in driver 3.8... Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set."

Answer (score 0):

Cause:

Slave and driver are using different versions in your case.

Fix:

1. Install Python 3.8 version in slaves.
2. Modify the **spark/conf/spark-env.sh** file and add **PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/lib/python3.8**

Comment: I have already python 3.9 version installed.also all the lines in spark-end.sh file is commented.in which option then you ask me to add PYSPARK_PYTHON ? at the end right? PYSPARK_PYTHON variable is already added in environment variable list in the system.also I could not find any path in my system as /usr/local/lib/..please guide me if my understanding is anywhere wrong. to let you know that in general I can execute pyspark codes in notebook ,even the pipelined rdd got created on mapping the dataframe.the error only faced while using toDF for rdd to df conversion.

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1010.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1010.0 (TID 32154, LTIN214271.cts.com, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back. `